# Spring JDBCTemplate other MySQL datasource than apache commons?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate to perform SQL operations on an apache commons datasource (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource) and when the service is up and running to long, i end up getting this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: StatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM vendor ORDER BY name]; The last packet successfully received from the server was 64,206,061 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 64,206,062 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 64,206,061 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 64,206,062 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
    at com.cable.comcast.neto.nse.taac.dao.VendorDao.getAllVendor(VendorDao.java:25)
    at com.cable.comcast.neto.nse.taac.controller.RemoteVendorAccessController.requestAccess(RemoteVendorAccessController.java:78)
```

I have tried adding the 'autoReconnect=true' to the connection string, but this problem still occurs.  Is there another datasource that can be used that will manage the reconnecting for me?

Answer (score 1):

BasicDataSource can manage keeping the connections alive for you.  You need to set the following properties :

```
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 120000 // Two minutes
testOnBorrow = true
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 120000 // Two minutes
minIdle = (some acceptable number of idle connections for your server)
```

These will configure the data source to keep continually test your connections, and expire and remove them if they become stale. There's a number of other properties on the basic data source that you may want to consider checking into as well to tweak your connection pooling performance.  I've run into some strange problems in the past where I was having issues with my database access and it all came down to how the connection pool was configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to C3PO:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"destroy-method="close">
   <property name="user" value="${db.username}"/>
   <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
   <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}"/>
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
   <property name="initialPoolSize" value="0"/>
   <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
   <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
   <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="600"/> <!--in seconds-->
</bean>
```

grettings
pacovr